# rectangles in beamer background canvas

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I am trying to create a custom title page in Beamer, and I've tried many things, but I'm just helpless with all the solutions I found.

I would like to create only in the title page, the following structure:

A wide rectangle on top (from side to side) with blue color (width=slidewidth, hight 3 cm), then should come my presentation text and other info, and in the bottom I wan to put the same rectangle ... (width=slidewidth, hight 3 cm).

I would like the rectangle to be part of the canvas, so I could insert the institute logo overlaid above the bottom rectangle. Any help would be appreciated.

Oz

UPDATE:

I managed to insert the fancy rectangels, but they are inside the text space, and I can't put them yet inside the footer and headers ...

here is what I did:

```
 \setbeamertemplate{title page}
   {
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2cm,wd=\paperwidth]{title in head/foot}
   \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
% {\centering \hskip3.5cm \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{FZD_LOGO.png}}
% \vskip1.25cm
\end{beamercolorbox}%

  \centering{
    {
    \usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}
    \inserttitle
    } 
    }
%     \vskip5cm
\vskip1.cm
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2cm,wd=\paperwidth]{title in head/foot}
\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}
{\centering \hskip3.5cm \includegraphics[scale=0.15]{FZD_LOGO.png}}
\end{beamercolorbox}%
% \end{minipage}
}
```

Sample output:

[image: sample output]

Comment: I still don't understand how to control the color of these boxes ...

Comment: @Oz: if you would show a small compilable example, the readers could test and improve it. Without code to work on, I just can recommend to use one of the packages `atbegshi`, `eso-pic` or `textpos`. The letter is not hard to use. Or edit footline and headline templates accordingly.

Comment: @Stefan I  put a link bellow.

Comment: I edited your question to embed the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi 
some thing like this could help:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\title{Stackxchng} 
\author{McCool} 
\institute{sth}
\date{the day the music died}   



\begin{document} 

\setbeamercolor{my thing}{fg=red, bg=black}% you can use every beamer color 
 \setbeamertemplate{title page}
   { 
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2cm,wd=\paperwidth, left, sep=.5cm]{my thing}
 \color{black}Upper % use every color you want
\end{beamercolorbox}%
\vskip0pt plus 1filll % see beamerusersguide

\begin{centering} % some Text Macros
 \inserttitle 

  \insertsubtitle 

 \insertauthor 

 \insertdate 

  \insertinstitute 

   \inserttitlegraphic
\end{centering}
\vskip0pt plus 1filll % again tantau magical
\leavevmode \begin{beamercolorbox}[ wd=\paperwidth, ht=2cm, sep=.5cm]{my thing}
  \color{black} Lower % or what ever you like
\end{beamercolorbox}%
}



\frame[plain]{\titlepage} % PLAIN!
\frame{just a frame}
\end{document}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yep, it sure helps ! that did it for me ...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is edit the `background` template, which goes over the canvas and under the text.  Put that inside a group with your title page and it will only affect the title page.

```
\mode<all>{\bgroup}

\setbeamertemplate{background{% draw stuff...
}

\begin{frame}
   \maketitle
\end{frame}

\mode<all>{\egroup}
```

Comment: http://img835.imageshack.us/i/screenshot2mp.png this is a link to what I am trying to achieve.