# Two images to fill one beamer frame: most appropriate method?

Tags: beamer, graphics

Suppose I have two images: one a solid blue square and another a yellow. What is the most appropriate way to divide and fill an **entire** beamer frame with these images? Horizontally (i.e., left half blue right half yellow)? Vertically? (i.e., top half blue bottom half yellow)

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31565/same-indentation-of-itemize-and-itemize-in-columns/31593#31593) provides a method, but it involves low-level operations. Another post (can't find the link now) suggests using TikZ.

Is there a third that doesn't involve low-level operations or complicated external packages? I'm confused. I'd think this task wouldn't be all that difficult.

Comment: What do you mean by **entire**? Do you still wish to have the theme bars on the top/bottom? Margins? Place for the navigation buttons? Or do you want it to look just like someone took a page out of another pdf file and pasted it to your carefully-themed document?

Comment: `\frame{\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth}{image1}\includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth}{image2}}`? Might not fill the full height, though.

Comment: You can use `\usebackgroundtemplate` before the frame

Comment: For other examples see [this](http://mprnotes.wordpress.com/2009/08/14/changing-background-image-of-latex-beamer/) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame) or [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/rectangles-in-beamer-background-canvas)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I mean the latter, like someone took a page out of another pdf file.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I'm trying to fill the **full** frame. The method you mention (for one image) leaves small margins at the head and foot and also some large margins on the left and right.

Comment: @Marco: Yes, that does work. I'm still not able to get the two images to fill vertically. I guess I don't want to think of what I'm adding as a background image. But if there's no easier way, I'll take it.

Comment: Did you play with the `height` parameter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the standard `\includegraphics` command setting  the proper values for the width and height in terms of `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight`; a box (in this case `\makebox`) will prevent an overfull box; using `plain` for the frames will remove the headline, footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cat1}%
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{cat2}}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{cat1}}\\\nointerlineskip
\makebox[\linewidth]{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=0.5\paperheight]{cat2}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\paperwidth` is hardly correct here because `\paperwidth` is larger than `\linewidth`.

Comment: @Igor: you're wrong: since I used `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}`, LaTeX doesn't care if the contents of the box overflows the dimension.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: First, there's still a thin white horizontal line in the second. I tried `\setlength{\baselineskip}{0pt}` and `\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` locally and had no success. Secondly, how did that work? Could you explain? Is this a hack or an intended use of `\makebox`? What do you mean "will prevent an overfull box"? It looks like the graphics overfilled the box to fill the frame. Thx for the help!

Comment: @brianjd: you said "there's still a thin white horizontal line in the second". In the second what? Please explain in more detail what are you referring to with "in the second". On the other hand, the use of `\makebox` it's not a hack; it's an intended use. As I said in my previous reply, using `\makebox[\linewidth]{...}` makes LaTeX let the contents of the box overflow its dimension without producing an overfull box.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: The top (almost) half is blue. The bottom (almost) half is yellow. And there's a thin white horizontal line separating the two. I'm guessing this is just the standard white-space that goes between two lines.

Comment: @brianjd: Ah, now I see. Yes. I forgot a `\nointerlineskip`. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: In the end I used your idea but with `\resizebox` instead of `\makebox`. It generalized to a number of other scenarios (not specifically asked for in my question) more nicely

Answer (score 12):

Here is a very simple solution via `columns`.

[image] [image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.5\paperwidth}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{.5\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
    \column{.5\paperwidth}
    \textcolor{yellow}{\rule{.5\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \begin{columns}
    \column{\paperwidth}
    \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}}\\\nointerlineskip
    \textcolor{yellow}{\rule{\paperwidth}{.5\paperheight}}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This even worked on a decorated, non-plain frame with a custom theme.

Comment: @ojdo Without `plain` option, the result seems correct... but material (here, `\rule`s) is too long!

Comment: I just used it with `\includegraphics` like the OP. The result looks fine for me.